# Azure data factory and Log analytics

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics

I want to perform some validation checks in ADF on my input data and any validation failures want to capture into Azure log analytics.

Can someone guide me how to capture the custom logs into log analytics through Azure Data Factory please.

Any example dataflow/pipeline would be very helpful.

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: You can refer to [Keeping Azure Data Factory metrics and pipeline-run data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#keeping-azure-data-factory-metrics-and-pipeline-run-data)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to be able to get the Azure Monitor logs for ADF and query/store these logs?

Well the good news is most of the information you would want to see is already collected through Azure Monitor.

One of the simple methods to pull the information is to use the Azure Monitor REST API. You can then store the response into a file or table, or you can just query the api for specific pipelines or triggers etc.

Here is a link with example of Authorization and using the Azure Monitor API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/rest-api-walkthrough#authenticating-azure-monitor-requests

This is an example of the HTTP URL using the Azure Monitor REST API to get Activity Run data (Dynamic content syntax):

```
@{concat('https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/', linkedService().SubscriptionID, '/resourceGroups/', linkedService().ResourceGroupName, '/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/', linkedService().DataFactoryName, '/pipelineruns/', linkedService().RunID, '/queryActivityruns?api-version=2018-06-01')}
```

Here are all the different ADF Metrics that can be pulled from Azure Monitor:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#data-factory-metrics

Here is an example of a REST Linked service in ADF that can be used to call the rest api:
[image: REST API Linked Service]

You could then create a dataset that will pass all the values to the linked service so that you can call the API, and copy the response to a DB, like here:
[image: Rest API copy activity example]

This particular example is getting the status of a specific Pipeline RunID, but it can be much more broad than that.
Here is what the request body looks like so that I could filter to just failed pipelines in the last day:
[image: REST API Body]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the details. My requiremet is,  I want to perform some sort of validation on every datset. For example want check the content of the file matches with the defined format and if it doesn't match I want to log the details into log analytics. Can you suggest me how to capture these details and write into analytics please.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this being possible. Let me know if you figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking into this myself, as far as I can tell you would have to use a REST or HTTP connector to send a POST request to the HTTP Data Collector API in Log Analytics. More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/logs/data-collector-api