# How to pass runid of a pipeline dynamically while using web activity with GET metho

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to get the running status of a particular pipeline in ADF from a different pipeline in same ADF instance.

I am using web activity with GET method, but issue with it is that every time I have to put the RunId of that pipeline manually in below URL. I am not able to pass it dynamically.
Like it takes pipeline RunId by itself.

GET [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}?api-version=2018-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/%7BfactoryName%7D/pipelineruns/%7BrunId%7D?api-version=2018-06-01)

I tried using @pipeline().RunId

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for: you have to know the pipeline RunId in order to request its status. If you are in Pipeline A and want to know the status of a run for Pipeline B, then you must know the RunId of the pipeline B instance. @pipeline().RunId will get you the RunId for Pipeline A, so is not relevant here.

Comment: Exactly this @pipeline().RunId will give run I'd of pipeline B . What I did is i created one parameter in pipeline B and that parameter holds the value of run I'd for pipeline B.I want to pass that value in my URL  /{runid}?api ...   My actual requirement is to get Runing status of pipeline B from pipeline A. For that I have to pass the RunId of pipeline B and I want that to be passed dynamically.  Do you have any suggestions how I can achieve it

Comment: This template is not working for you right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252383/how-to-get-output-parameter-from-executed-pipeline-in-adf

Do you have log analytics enabled for ADF?

Answer (score 0):

> I have to put the RunId of that pipeline manually in below URL. I am not able to pass it dynamically.

**There is no direct way to pass the parameter from one pipeline to another pipeline.**

To achieve this, we have to use execute pipeline to execute **Pipeline B** and the fetch the **run id** of that pipeline.

[image]

To get pipeline run id of executed **Pipeline B** in **Pipeline A** `@activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelinerunid`

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When using the Azure Function ADF Activity, you can also use concat method to send along a query string:

[image]

Dynamic content code: `@{concat('MyAzureFunction?runId=', pipeline().RunId)}`