# How to stop running pipeline in data factory if is taking longer then expected time to execute and send an email alert?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I have scheduled trigger to execute pipeline in data factory , I want to stop execution if pipeline run more then expected time and send email notification to notify about log running pipeline. I am new to data factory and google it to achieve this but could not find any useful things

I tried using logic app to send an email but could not able to create workflow as needed. I have tried capturing runid and trigger stattime in table and use it in logic app to control the flow but unfortunately workflow is not running as expected

Answer (score 0):

Datafactory has alerts and metrics built in. Here you should be able to achieve what you are looking for

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, also could you please suggest the way I can stop execution as well for log running pipeline?

Comment: Easiest thing to do might be to just do an API call for all pipelines that are in progress, with a start date more than X amount of time ago. Those are the pipelines you'd want to cancel. You could then just run a for each on that list to run API call to cancel those runs.

Set that pipeline to run every hour, and you should be golden. That's a pretty simple catch all. You can refer to this SO post for that API Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252383/how-to-get-output-parameter-from-executed-pipeline-in-adf/68402482#68402482